# A rowset based on the SQL command was not returned by the OLE DB provider

Tags: sql, ssis

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this issue? I am calling a sproc in SSIS. All I want it to do is create a file if any new records are updated or inserted into a table. That table checks another source table to see if anything changed in that table and then adds it to the copy table, if there are any updates or changes to the source table I want a file to get created and if not we don't want it to do anything.

I have tested the logic and everything seems to work fine but once I try to run the sproc in SSIS it gives the error message, "A rowset based on the SQL command was not returned by the OLE DB provider." Initially I thought this means that it is erroring out because no rows are being returned but even when there are rows being returned I still get the very same error message. I can parse the query and preview the results in SSIS but it still turns red when run and gives that error message.

Below is the code to my sproc. Any help or ideas would be so appreciated!

```
    USE [dev02]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_VoidReasons]    Script Date:            8/25/2016 11:54:44 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------   ----
    Author:         Andrej Friedman
    Create date:    07/27/2016
    Description:    This sproc assists SSIS in creating a file but only when a                    new row has been added to the VoidReasonsLookup table 
    that didnt exist there before or if the code or description has changed in    that table. The table is compared to the prod1.dbo.miscde 
table for diferences and only for the Void Reasons of that table (mcmspf = 'cv'). 
History:        
SampleCall:     EXEC [dbo].[usp_VoidReasons]
    --truncate table dev02.dbo.VoidReasonsLookup
    --select * from dbo.VoidReasonsLookup
    --update VoidReasonsLookup set Description = 'BB' where Description = 'BENEFIT CODE ADJUSTMENT'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_VoidReasons] 

as


declare @ImportDate as date = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) 


insert into VoidReasonsLookup (Code, [Description])


--Change #1 -- New Code and Description

--This will insert a new row in the VoidReasons table where the Code and description doesnt exist there but exists in the source table. 

select (M.mcmscd_1 + M.mcmscd_4) as Code, mcmsds as [Description] from prod1.dbo.miscde M 

left join VoidReasonsLookup VL

on M.mcmscd_1 + M.mcmscd_4 = VL.Code

where M.mcmspf = 'cv'

and VL.Code is null



--Change #2 -- Code dropped off source table so we need it gone from the VoidReasons table

--This will delete rows where the Code doesnt exists in the source table any longer


delete from VL from VoidReasonsLookup as VL

left join prod1.dbo.miscde as M

on VL.Code = M.mcmscd_1 + M.mcmscd_4

where M.mcmscd_1 + M.mcmscd_4 is null


--Change #3 -- Description has changed for a certain code in the source table.

--This will update the Description to the source table if it is different in the VoidReasons table and update the ImportDate to today when that update took place. 


update VL

set VL.[Description] = M.mcmsds,

VL.ImportDate = @ImportDate

from dbo.VoidReasonsLookup as VL

join prod1.dbo.miscde as M 

on VL.Code = M.mcmscd_1 + M.mcmscd_4

where VL.[Description] <> M.mcmsds

and M.mcmspf = 'cv'




--This will give back everything in the VoidReasons table but only if todays date is the same as the ImportDate column of the table. 

--This will mean that today a record was inserted or updated. 


If exists(select ImportDate from VoidReasonsLookup

where ImportDate = @ImportDate)

select * from VoidReasonsLookup

else 

print 'no changes detected in VoidReasons table'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add SET NOCOUNT ON and at the end you are selecting resultset basedon condition, SSIS expects resultset always based on output type which you configured. You can use empty resultset as an output will solve the problem

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not sure I fully understand. You're saying if I tell SSIS to handle an empty result set it should be fine? Even when I get a result set back SSIS still errors.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out everything, rerun and see if you still get the error.  Uncomment parts until you get the error.  Once you get the error, you know what is causing the issue.

Comment: You mean in SSMS? In SSMS the stored procedure runs just fine, the logic seems good. Its just in SSIS where it doesn't run without an error.